# How can I get my userform to select it's droplist data from a separate worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that fills out a row of information into an excel sheet. The excel sheet has two spreadsheets, one for data entry, and one for the 3 droplists that are in the userform. I want to delete this second sheet and make it into its own workbook. My question here is how can I write the VBA code to select the data from the droplist workbook (called "Client and Project Droplists.xlsx") to populate the droplists in the userform in the first workbook (called "Expense Reports Test.xlsm")? My current code is attached below.

```
Private Sub cboClient_Change()
Me.cboProject = ""
Select Case Me.cboClient

Case "Wells Fargo"
    Me.cboProject.RowSource = "WellsFargoProjects"
Case "BLUSA"
    Me.cboProject.RowSource = "BLUSAProjects"
Case "JP Morgan"
    Me.cboProject.RowSource = "JPMProjects"
End Select

End Sub
```

I will be at work for the next few hours so any additional information can be requested in the questions/comments section. Would really appreciate help on this task.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Is **Client and Project Droplists.xlsx** already open when the sub runs??

Comment: I am using Excel 2007 reporter. Gary's Student I've tried it with Client and Droplist opened and while it's closed.

Comment: Instead of putting that sheet for populating the comboboxes into it's own workbook, I'd recommend just hiding that worksheet.  Is there a specific reason you need to it to be a separate workbook?

Comment: yeah I echo tigeravatar's comment. It is not good practice to have drop down menus in a another workbook. Make the worksheet very hidden using a macro. Nobody will be able to see it.

Comment: Yes Tiger I should've mentioned this earlier. Several people will be using these expense reports in my office. I want to have one centralized list of projects that we can regularly update that each person's expense report sheet will reference for their droplists, rather than having each person have to individually update their droplists, which is more time consuming and prone to discrepancies in spelling errors.

Comment: Yes I agree with you both, it would be much, much easier to have a hidden worksheet for the drop lists. But for long term efficiency a shared spreadsheet for every employee to use would be best. We have a company private network where I am uploading these expense report sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My co-worker and I share a lot of data and work in excel quite a bit, so we have created quite a few shared tables on network drives for use in our utilities.

One method we have employed is opening a global list, copying it locally, and using it to populate a dropdown:

```
Sub GetStatusCodeList()

Dim ThisWb
Set ThisWb = ThisWorkbook

If Dir("\\SERVERNAME\GlobalUtilities\GlobalTables.xlsx") = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open "\\SERVERNAME\GlobalUtilities\GlobalTables.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GlobalTables").UsedRange.Copy ThisWb.Sheets("DropDown").Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Another method simply reads the cells from a global list and writes them directly into the conditional formatting list. This particular code creates an array of available sheets and uses it to populate a dropdown:

```
Sub CreateSheetDropdown()

Dim sheetCounter, i
Dim theSheets() As String
ReDim theSheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count + 1) As String

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    theSheets(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next i

With ThisWb.Sheets(Mtab).Range("SourceTabName")
    .Value = theSheets(1)
    .Validation.Delete
    '.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    '    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(theSheets, ",")
    .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(theSheets, ",")
    .Validation.ShowError = False
    .Interior.color = RGB(250, 200, 200)
End With

End Sub
```

Finally, this code creates a dropdown in a userform from a global list that we keep on our shared drive:

```
Private Sub UpdateDropdowns()

Dim thisWorkbook
Set thisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
If Dir(TABLEPATH) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("GlobalTables File Not Found - Critical Error")
    Me.Hide
    Exit Sub
End If
Workbooks.Open Filename:=TABLEPATH, ReadOnly:=True

'---------------------------------------------
'Method would load from GlobalTables.xlsx
'---------------------------------------------
'Load Utility Names
For Each c In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(UTIL_SHEET).Range("A2:A" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(UTIL_SHEET).Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(UTIL_SHEET).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Cells
    AddUtilToAll (c.Value)
Next c

End Sub

Private Sub AddUtilToAll(ByVal s)
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If InStr(c.Name, "UtilityCombo") Then c.AddItem (s)
Next c
End Sub
```

Probably the easiest method to employ is the first one - just open the workbook stored on a shared drive and copy each dropdown list locally. You can run this in the Worksheet initialize function so that the dropdowns are updated each time you open the file.

Hope this helps, let me know if you want more information.

**Edit:**

It's probably easier to read here.

Just link your dropdown to a named range:

[image: NamedRange]

```
'Delete the old named range
ThisWorkbook.Names("TestDropdown").Delete 
'Define the new named range
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TestDropdown", RefersTo:=Range("A1:A25")
```

Comment: I like this idea of having each separate list copy the information automatically from the global list. I'll try to implement this and get back to you on how it goes. I see that this changes the information, does it also change the dropdown list in the userform, or will everyone have to manually select the new data for each list?

Comment: Just link your dropdown to a named range and redefine the named range after your import. ThisWorkbook.Names("PrintArea").Delete ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DropdownList", RefersTo:=Range("A1:A25")

Comment: If you're doing this in a userform, you can clear the dropdown list using ListBox1.Clear and rebuild it using ListBox1.RowSource = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!TestDropdown", although you may be able to do the same thing by simply deleting and redefining the range.